# MSTSC Ghost Typing "C"

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop

A colleague has an odd issue.

- When connected to a server via `MSTSC` (microsoft terminal services client) the character C is typed into any text editor (SSMS / Notepad / etc) he opens.  (Oddly this doesn't occur on all in-focus text boxes though).
- When connecting to the same server via `RDCMAN 2.7` (remote desktop connection manager) this issue does not occur.
- On his local machine, the computer's volume slowly decreases.

It feels like a stuck key issue; presumably with some control character involved which explains the odd behaviour with `MSTSC`.  We've tried mashing the keys in case something's stuck but with no luck.  Haven't yet tried writing a script to monitor for & report key presses; though may shortly.

We've disconnected & reconnected to the remote server with no change.

He's currently restarting his machine to see if that resolves...

Comment: Does this affect MSTSC on multiple client computers, or only on that particular one?

Comment: @grawity: The issue impacted all servers accessed via MSTSC.

Comment: NB: The reboot resolved this (sadly; was interesting behaviour; I would have liked a more interesting fix)...

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the client machine resolved the issue.

Comment: over the years, I've gone from rebooting every day religiously (preventatively) under 9x, to rebooting weekly under 2k/XP to rebooting monthly (7/10). sometimes these days, I'm actually forgetting the first rule of windows troubleshooting: "Have you tried turning it off and back on again?"